# split semicolon delimiter SQL to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, split

Just want to ask for help.
I'm trying to split delimited values with a semicolon as a delimiter.
Comma cannot be replaced to the semicolon since there are values that have comma.

```
ID   Value
1   | A&B;C;D;E, F
```

Transform to:

```
ID   Value
1    A&B
1    C
1    D
1    E, F
```

I tried tweaking the SQL scripts that i got online but to no success

```
SELECT F1.ID,
 O.splitdata 
FROM
 (
 SELECT OldID,
 cast('<X>'+replace((SELECT ColumnName + '' FOR XML PATH('')),';','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as xmlfilter from TableName F
 )F1
 CROSS APPLY
 ( 
 SELECT fdata.D.value('.','varchar(max)') as splitdata 
 FROM f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') as fdata(D)) O
```

It works for some of my columns but if the columns have special or Illegal characters it outputs this error:

```
Msg 9411, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
XML parsing: line 1, character 16, semicolon expected
```

Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of string splitting techniques out there, you don't have to use an XML based function. Read Aaron bertrand's [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) and choose a different funcftion.

Comment: A quick Google for something like `sql split string on delimiter` gives loads of options, including the excellent article linked above by [Zohar Peled](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3094533/zohar-peled) - have you tried any of the easily-Googleable alternative approaches?

Comment: if you remove & your query will work fine @mirelle

Comment: @mohan111 I just posted an answer which allows such characters in XML-string-splitting.

Comment: The linked *possible duplicate* (by Serg) is a great list of possible approaches, but quite old. Many answers there are outdated... I'll close this as duplicate with the hint, to look there for newer answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not like a function, or if you do not have the rights to create a new function, you can use the quite fast XML approach. In your case it needs some extra effort to get this XML-safe (due to special characters and the `;` as delimiter):

```
Declare @Dummy table (ID int, SomeTextToSplit varchar(max))
Insert Into @Dummy values
 (1,'A&B;C;D;E, F')
,(2,'"C" & "D";<C>;D;E, F');

DECLARE @Delimiter VARCHAR(10)=';';
WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(SomeTextToSplit,@Delimiter,'§§Split$me$here§§') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),'§§Split$me$here§§','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS SplitMe
    FROM @Dummy
)
SELECT Casted.*
      ,x.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS Part 
FROM Casted
CROSS APPLY SplitMe.nodes('/x') AS A(x)
```

The result

```
1   A&B
1   C
1   D
1   E, F
2   "C" & "D"
2   <C>
2   D
2   E, F
```

Comment: Very nice - migrated into my XML parse function

Comment: Thanks for this one! it actually worked. Only note that the NULL values are turned to blanks. but nonetheless, it's working perfectly. It ran for 28 secs compared to my Cursor Script which ran for 10 mins.

Comment: @MirelleGameng, not quite true... If your string contains two *semi-colons* one after the other (`SomeValue;;More`) there is no character between these two. This is not read as a blank (=`space`), but as an *empty string* (=*zero-length-string*). You can use `NULLIF()` to translate this into `NULL` if needed. If this works, please accept the answer, thx!

Comment: Already accepted. Thanks again @Shnugo :)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 with a UDF**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int, Value varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'A&B;C;D;E, F')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K](A.Value,';') B
```

**Option 2 without a UDF**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.Value,';','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
              ) B
```

**Both Return**

```
ID  RetSeq  RetVal
1   1       A&B
1   2       C
1   3       D
1   4       E, F
```

**This UDF is XML Safe and VERY fast**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(25))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L)))
    From   cte4 A
);
--Orginal Source http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
--Much faster than str-Parse, but limited to 8K
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the function below to split a string by a specific delimiter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))        
returns @temptable TABLE (SplitValue varchar(8000))        
as        
begin        
    declare @idx int        
    declare @slice varchar(8000)        

    select @idx = 1        
       if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return        

    while @idx!= 0        
    begin        
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)        
        if @idx!=0        
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)        
        else        
            set @slice = @String        

        if(len(@slice)>0)   
            insert into @temptable(SplitValue) values(@slice)        

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)        
        if len(@String) = 0 break        
    end    
return       
end
```

Let me know if you have any queries.

Thanks .

Comment: Approaches with loops are out-dated...