# Iterate through column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

My user table has a column that contains comma seperated values,
as each user can have multiple accounts. Please note that I can not change
this structure.

```
UserID  | Accounts  
---------------------
1       | ABC,DEF,GHI
2       | JKL, MNO
```

Based on this table, I need to create a new table that contains one row for each account:

```
UserID  | Account   
---------------------
1       | ABC
1       | DEF
1       | GHI
2       | JKL
2       | MNO
```

Comment: Hint:  `STRING_SPLIT()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+split+string+to+rows

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT()` is not availabe in the version of SQL I am stuck with

Comment: Check the duplicate link for a number of other options.  The best thing to do might be to not even bring CSV data into SQL Server in the first place.

Comment: If you can't create a Table-Valued Function, take a peek at Option 2 ... without UDF   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41999151/split-semicolon-delimiter-sql-to-rows/41999472#41999472